# How can I make grid tiles/plane transparent

Tags: unity, tower-defense, grid

I have made a grid using multiple planes. Now I want to place a image on this grid so that user cant see the grid I have made and I ll have access of all points of the image using grid.

The problem is I am unable to place image on it, it shows me grid that I made before. I have tried Materials/Shader -> Transparent/Diffuse, but some blocks are still visible. How can I make grid tiles transparent ?

Comment: can you share some image of your problem?

Comment: I am still having problems, I will try to upload the image. Basically problem is: I have multiple planes just like 2D array and I am placing my simple background over the grid, but on playing there are all the planes(Grid) displayed which I dont want the user to see. I only wants the user to see map(my background image) not grid.

Comment: Can't you just skip them in your rendering process

Answer (score 1):

Without an image of the problem it is fairly hard to answer, but if it is a rendering problem then add the image render after the grid render or just skip rendering the grid.

Answer (score 1):

As Gajet mentioned, you can simply remove or disable the MeshRenderer Component off all the tiles/planes you not want to show. (They still exist for collisions, but will not be visible.)